# Axes but no lines when printing plot in Octave for windows

Tags: plot, octave

When attempting to print a plot to .png in Octave 3.8.1.1 on Windows 8 64-bit, the axes plot, but the line I'm plotting won't print. The plot I'm creating is:

```
> t = 0:0.1:6.28318;
> plot (t, sin(t));
> print figure.png
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

And the image saved to disk:

[image]

So the axes are showing up fine, but the line I've plotted is completely missing!

I have gs9.09 (win32) installed, with [epstool win32](http://fossies.org/linux/misc/ghost/ghostgum/epstool-3.08-win32.zip/) copied into gs's /bin directory, which is being set in my `%HOMEPATH%\.octaverc` as:

```
cmd_path = getenv ("path");
gs_path = 'C:\Programs\gs\gs9.09\bin';
if (isempty (strfind (cmd_path, gs_path)))
   setenv ('path', strcat (cmd_path, pathsep (), gs_path));
endif
```

I am running the windows GUI version via `w8-octave-gui.bat`.

**EDIT**
On a fresh launch with the following commands to set gnuplot as the graphics toolkit before launching any plots (from @Andy's comments), I get a blank white image for all images without `-dpngalpha` (1, 2, 4, 5) and completely transparent images with no content for images *with* `-dpngalpha` (3, 6):

```
>> graphics_toolkit("gnuplot");
>> graphics_toolkit()
ans = gnuplot
>> t = 0:0.1:6.3;
>> plot(t,sin(t));
>> print ("1.png");
>> print ("-dpng", "2.png");
>> print ("-dpngalpha", "3.png");
>> axis("off");
>> print ("4.png");
>> print ("-dpng", "5.png");
>> print ("-dpngalpha", "6.png");
```

Halp!

Comment: Have you tried with a different `graphics_toolkit`?

Comment: Congrats for this well-written question. Adding to @am304's comment, please also try with alternative syntax: `print ('figure.png','-dpng')`.

Comment: @am304 - I wasn't aware of that option, thank you. Using `available_graphics_toolkits()` lists `gnuplot` and `fltk` on my system. Switching to `gnuplot` I can succesfully print only .emf files, and can send the plot to my printer (progress!). Every other format I tried with `gnuplot` prints a blank white image (.png, .pdf, .jpg). When I try .gif the application crashes (if saving from the plot window) or reports `the gnuplot terminal, "gif", is not available` if run from the command window. -- I would ideally like .png output, any thoughts on that?

Comment: @juliohm - thanks! using the alternative syntax had no effect with either `fltk` or `gnuplot`.

Comment: @cod3monk3y, consider a [bug report](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave).

Comment: @cod3monk3y: I think you've hit this bug https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=42534. None of the maintainers was able to reproduce this so I guess it's a rare constellation with your setup and perhaps graphic card driver. Can you try `t = 0:0.1:6.28318;
plot (t, sin(t));
axis ("off")
print ("-dpngalpha", "figure.png")` this disables the axes and saves a transparent PNG. If you see the sin, then the reason for your problem is, that (perhaps because of rounding errors) the line is behind the white axes box.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've hit this bug: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?42534

I know you answered to juliohm's comment that switching to gnuplot doesn't has an effect but I can't believe this. You have to execute
`graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")`
before any command which creates a plot figure. To be sure you can run "close all" before.

The reason for your problem is possibly that the line is printed behind the white background due to some rounding errors in the z-depth. Can you please try
**EDIT: these command when graphics_toolkit fltk is enabled (should be the case with a default install and a fresh start):**

```
t = 0:0.1:6.28318;
plot (t, sin(t));
axis ("off");
print ("-dpngalpha", "out.png")
```

to verify this? This doesn't solve your problem but helps the Octave maintainers to find the problem.

Comment: I've executed this as recommended, with no change. The only difference is `-dpngalpha` saves the image transparent instead of just full white. See edit to the question with the full execution log, executed from the launch of the app.

Comment: Where did you download your used installer? Is it from http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/? Can you start octave with its commandline (and not with the experimental GUI) and try printing? Thanks

Comment: @cod3monkey: The commands in my answer were intended to be run with fltk as graphics toolkit, not with gnuplot. Sorry that I wasn't clear on this, but because your first figure from your question shows FLTK, I thought it's clear that we first try to get FLTK printing running and gnuplot is only a option if FLTK doesn't work for you.

Comment: I don't recall where I downloaded it from, but that link is showing "visited" so I'll posit "yes, that's where I got it.". I'm running `3.8.1-1-portable`. When I `cd` to the octave bin directory `c:\programs\octave\3.8.1-1-portable\octave-3.8.1\bin` and run those commands, I still get the empty, transparent .png. Additionally, the Figure window is unresponsive. It doesn't render anything when it first displays, and windows marks it `(Not Responding)`. It does flash when I issue `print` but then ends up with a black background with a blue sin curve plotted, sometimes offset strangely.

Comment: I'm going to try upgrading to 3.8.2-1 non-portable. I'll report back.

Comment: 3.8.2 (non-portable) install freezes not only just the plot window but also now the command shell and the GUI, requiring a forced shutdown of the application, whenever I issue the `plot` command.

Comment: Have you used the octave-gui.bat which has to be placed in the octave folder and linked from here http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/README.html to start octave?

Comment: Yes, that is the file I used to start octave.

Comment: this worked for me when running octave under a Debian Virtualbox guest

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.

For me the solution was bypassing the system graphics driver and switching to OpenGL software rendering with Mesa. To achieve this I downloaded the windows binary of Mesa that is linked on http://qt-project.org/wiki/Cross-compiling-Mesa-for-Windows and copied the included opengl32.dll into octave's bin directory. Afterwards the print command worked fine.

The Mesa binary from the link above is built with LLVMpipe and seems to run reasonably fast.